# Changing value of an atttribute of NSManagedObject doesn't reflect on DiffableDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

So I'm using the (iOS13)(XCode 13.1) `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` and `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`. Whenever I change an attribute in one of my `CoreData`'s `NSManagedObject`s, the DiffableAPI doesn't capture this and change and react automatically. I'm suspecting this is because ManagedObject doesn't take properties into consideration when it does the isEqual operation. I cannot also override ManagedObject's isEqual function. How do I solve this?

Comment: This is solved by calling setting `animatingDifferences` as `false` in the  `apply(_ snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<SectionIdentifierType, ItemIdentifierType>, animatingDifferences: Bool = true, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)` method. 
This hard refreshes the data without animating it. As of Xcode 11.4.1 there's no proper documentation for this method

Answer (score 1):

***Update***

Found an new solution. After watching [Making App with Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/230/) from WWDC 2019 again, it appears that we should use `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference` over `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<S,I>` when working with Core Data:

```swift
let dataSourceReference = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSourceReference(collectionView: collectionView) { collectionView, indexPath, anyObjectID in
  guard 
    let objectID = anyObjectID as? NSManagedObjectID,
    let <#myObject#> = managedObjectContext.object(with: objectID) as? <#MyObject#>
  else { return nil }

  /* dequeue, configure and return cell object here */
}

collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceReference
```

Then, apply the snapshot when the content change:

```swift
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeContentWith snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference) {
  dataSourceReference.applySnapshot(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
}
```

To create and apply a snapshot manually:

```swift
func applySnapshot(animated: Bool) {
  let ids = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.compactMap { $0.objectID as Any } ?? []
  let snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference()
  snapshot.appendSections(withIdentifiers: [<#someSection#>])
  snapshot.appendItems(withIdentifiers: ids, intoSectionWithIdentifier: <#someSection#>)
  
  dataSourceReference.applySnapshot(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animated)
}
```

Doing so, everything works as we expected, including when changing the attribute of an object.

---

I'm having the same issue. In my case, I'm using the `NSFetchedResultsController` to receive the model changes.

My workaround is to replace `controller(_:didChangeContentWith:)` with

```swift
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>,
          didChange anObject: Any,
                at indexPath: IndexPath?,
                    for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
                newIndexPath: IndexPath?
) {
  if type == .update {
    // apply snapshot without animation
  } else {
    // apply snapshot with animation
  }
}
```

to apply new snapshot accordingly.

Another workaround is, instead of creating an new snapshot every time you apply, you:

- initially, create an new snapshot and apply it to the data source
- when received model updates, ask the data source for an existing snapshot and modify it by calculating the differences, then apply it to the data source

This also fix the issue, but require a bit more work.

I end up using the former one.